# Android Studio wait for Bluetooth Enable

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm fairly new to programming and am trying to create an app that communicates via BluetoothLE with a peripheral device.

Now I was able to do all these things, but ran into a problem. If the phones bluetooth is activated after the App started it will crash as soon as I start scanning for devices. If the bluetooth is already activated when the App is starting there is no such problem.

Actually at the start of the app my programm is checking if bluetooth is enabled on the phone and if not asks the user to enable it, but it will lead down to the problem mentioned above, because it was enabled after the app started.

I'm using the following code for this request:

```
 if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
```

I hope to solve my problem by pausing the oncreate() method here until bluetooth is activated. But how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#setup), you have to check if the bluetooth is enabled, and if not, ask the user to activate it. that's what your code do.

---

What you seem to be missing, is to check the result. When the activity you hav opened to ask the user to activate bluetooth is finished, you have to check if the user has enabled it or not. if yes continue, if not do what you want (like close the app or re-ask).

To check that use [`onActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)). This method will be trigerred when the activity to activate bluetooth is finished. There check that you have returned from this activity and not from another using the request code (REQUEST_ENABLE_BT). Then check if bluetooth is enabled, if yes do your stuff, if not close the app (for example)

So you will have something like

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}

void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (btAdapter != null && btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            startDoingThings();
        } else {
            finnish();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the other things you do in your onCreate() after checking the bluetooth. Do not do it in onCreate() but in startDoingThings(). By doing this you will wait for the bluetooth to be enabled before doing your stuff.

Comment: thank you! this seems like exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunatly it didn't work. With this modifications the app starts without asking the user if he wants to activate the bluetooth. Instead the "startDoingthings();" method is called imediatly. And it behaves very strange. some invisibilities aren't set right and stuff.

Comment: I got it working with your help now. thanks a lot! The last problem was that I initialized my btScanner before checking for the bluetooth state.... I put this also in the startDoingThings(); method and now everything works flawlessly, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add Following  permission to Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Create a function

```
public void setBluetoothEnable(Boolean enable) {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter != null){
      if (enable) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        }
      } else {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then call this function

```
//For enable bluetooth
setBluetoothEnable(true);

//For disable bluetooth
setBluetoothEnable(false);
```

This worked for me